# How to fix Wkhtmltopdf incorrect page count

Tags: javascript, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to merge multiple bills into a single pdf. Every bill has multiple pages and every bill has unique header and footer. To print out page count I use JavaScript code from documentation example. When I build pdf from a single bill, page count is correct, but when I pass in all bills, page count is total sum of every bill page. Headers are printed ok, they are unique for every bill, only the page count is summed together. Is there a way to fix the page count?

Comment: can you show the code you use for pages? i use the standard shown in the wkhtmltopdf manual, and that always worked very well for me ( and i even manipulate the DOM and multiply the pages in javascript)

Answer (score 0):

No, because each page is processed separately. So for the first webpages you could never get the total page count correct anyways, because the other webpages are not processed yet and the footer is already on the PDFs.

Comment: There should be a way how I can count pages manually. Based on document height for example.